# Android: promo code for subscription version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have 3 versions of my app: free, basic and pro.
Pro requires a subscription but I'd like to create promo codes for a subscription that never ends. Is this possible? I could do this by creating some codes in my database but I'd prefer having just the Google check for this.

[image]

It's only 3 months max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subscription that never ends is not a subscription, therefore such functionality can't exist.

A solution for your requirement is to create a **non-consumable in-app Product** in the developer's console, and generate promo codes for it.

You will need to adjust your billing implementation to also query for in-app products (***SkuType.INAPP***), besides subscriptions.

Comment: I was looking for a promo code longer that that. Maybe one year or so but that's another option, thanks